# Facebook like count xslt

Tags: facebook, xslt, facebook-like

I want to show on a page the ammount of likes a page has. Below you find a siplified snippet of the code I have. Can anyone help me to just show the number of counts? At the moment I'm just getting a Facebook like button.

Thank you!

Thijs

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <fb:like url="" layout="button_count"></fb:like>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The count will come from Facebook when you this is loaded.  You cannot specify a count yourself nor get rid of the Facebook `Like` button.

[Facebook Like button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

**EDIT**

You might find that the Graphi API has what you are looking for

[Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

I have just looked at Insights.  You can view Likes etc. if you set up your page to use [Open Graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your anwser. I don't want to show a like button. I just want to show a number of the ammount of likes a link has.